# Convert Elastiflow network flow into 3D graphics

Tags: 3d, traffic, network-traffic, netflow

I am looking for a way to show Elastiflow's Netflow traffic in 3D graphics and I would like to know a solution that I could implement.

Flow Trafic Like:

[image: Example image]

The 3D presentation I would like to achieve would be something like this or similar.

[image: Result Example image]

[image: Result Example image]